# How do you syncronize a field from Inputs.form in ObservableHQ?

Tags: javascript, observable, observablehq

I have a notebook with several grouped forms that are using `Inputs.form` and I would like to synchronize them (i.e. https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/synchronized-inputs), such as with `Inputs.bind(..., viewof x)`.

For example, with a cell

```js
viewof my_form = Inputs.forms([
  my_field: Inputs.range([0, 100], {step: 1}),
])
```

I would like to effectively do the following

```js
Inputs.bind(Inputs.range([0, 100], {step: 1}), viewof my_form.my_field)
```

But of course `viewof my_form.my_field` is not valid.

Comment: You might consider asking on [the Observable forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/), where there are plenty of knowledgeable folks on these kinds of things. If you do so, it's generally best to include a link to a notebook. In addition to providing folks with code to start with, that helps you avoid syntactical errors, like the ones you've got in your code here.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I just figured out a solution which I'll answer here and also try to upstream to the Observable docs.

Answer (score 0):

An `Inputs.form` view will return an HtmlElement with multiple children. Using `(viewof form).children[i]` will return an input HtmlElement that can be used with `Inputs.bind`.

Here's an [example notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/dca8540d04be23c8), with the following cells.

```js
viewof form = Inputs.form({
  field: Inputs.range([0, 100], {label: "foo"}),
})
```

```js
Inputs.bind(Inputs.range([0, 100]), (viewof form).children[0])
```